# Как преобразовать timestamp в читаемое время не учитывая часовые пояса и переход на летнее время?

Tags: datetime, android, unixtimestamp, java, время

Имеется метод, для преобразования времени UTC в читаемый формат.

```
public static String convertUTC(final long time)
{
        final Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
        return format.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Но проблема в том, что получается время с учетом перехода на летнее и зимнее время, а так же учитывается часовой пояс на устройстве

Например если вызвать

```
convertUTC(1397676512436)
```

то вернется **2014:04:17 01:28:32**.  В этот момент на устройстве стоит часовой пояс **GMT+6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, нужно было добавить

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```